# MYSQL Join 2 tables with 2 relations table

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, export-to-csv

Hi I need to get data from a database but I can't figure out how do do it as is...

They have "boutiques" tables and "boutiques_categories" and a relation table between them name "boutiques_categories_categories"

here how they are setup :

```
boutiques
id    name
1     X_boutiques2_name
2     Y_boutiques_name

Boutique2
id   name
1    X_boutiques2_name
2    Y_boutiques2_name

boutiques_categories
id   name
1    X_categorie_name
2    Y_categorie_name

boutiques_categories_categories
boutique_id              categorie_id
X_boutique_id            X_categorie_id
Y_boutique_id            Y_categorie_id
```

I want to create a SQL to merge and print a CSV of the data like so :

```
export
boutiques_id    boutique_name     boutiques_categories_categorie_name
boutiques2_id   boutique2_name    boutiques_categories_categorie_name
```

I trying UNION those 2 table

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM boutiques A 
UNION select B.* FROM boutiques2 B
```

And it's working but now I need to Join the categorie name to it and I can't figure out how to do it. Tried :

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM boutiques A 
UNION select B.* 
FROM boutiques2 B 
 left join 
  boutiques_categories BC ON BC.id = 
   (
     SELECT BCC.categorie_id 
     FORM 
      boutiques_categories_categories BCC 
     WHERE BCC.boutique_id = BC.id
   )
```

But I get MYSQL error that I can't resolve.

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Thank for your time.

Comment: You don't need to use `union`. That is used to return multiple select statements as a single result. The `join` syntax is all that you need.

Comment: But i do need to have multiple select statement as I need to select the data from boutiques and boutique2 and then add the categorie name to the boutique data.

Comment: Sorry, I was just about to edit my comment after re-reading your question. You're right about the union. I'll write up a query shortly, if nobody else answers in the meantime.

Comment: Thank this would be really appreciate I'm still trying to figure out on my side but i'm not a SQL pro!

Comment: Please format the code properly.  It's hard for others to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can union (or `union all`, depending on what data you want)  `boutiques` and `Boutique2` into a derived table, and then join that to boutiques_categories through boutiques_categories_categories.

The table data that you included in your question doesn't seem completely accurate though. Specifically: boutiques_categories_categories containing boutique_id and categorie_id values that don't match the id columns of the associated tables. I'm just going to assume that boutiques_categories_categories have int ID values. If this is not the case, please clarify in the comments, and I can adjust the query appropriately.

Give this query a try, and see if it returns the data that you expect:

```
select 
    b.id, b.name, c.name
from
    -- Get the boutiques rows from the unioned tables
    (
        select id, name from boutiques
        union
        select id, name from Boutique2
    ) as b
    -- Join in boutiques_cateogires_categories
    join boutiques_categories_categories cc
        on (b.id=cc.boutique_id)
    -- Join in boutiques_categories
    join boutiques_categories c
        on (cc.categorie_id=c.id)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i needed! Sorry if my question wasn't very clear but you got it just right.

Comment: @SebastienB. Glad it worked for you!  Don't worry about your question. For future reference, it's best to present an exact example of your data, and then explain it separately. So rather than writing `X_boutique_id` in the `boutique_id` column, you should just write `1`, and then use the body of your question to explain "the boutique_id column matches the id in the boutique table".